# Search in file names but exclude certain file extensions using grep

Tags: linux, grep

```
 grep --exclude=\*.{mp3,jpg,pdf,png} -i "size\|log" | cut -c 32-|grep -v name1 |grep -v name2
```

it's not working for me
i want to do something like

```
ls -la |  grep --exclude=\*.{mp3,jpg,pdf,png} -i "size\|log" | cut -c 32-|grep -v name1 |grep -v name2
```

but it's not excluding those extensions

```
ls -la |  grep -i "size\|log" | cut -c 32-|grep -v name1 |grep -v name2 |grep -v "*.mp3"
```

is not working

the -r flag gives me the result but with the content of the file, i just wanna grep filename

Comment: `--exclude` is for grep to ignore files, not lines; are you looking for `grep -v` functionality?

Comment: It looks like `find` might be a better match for what you're doing.

Comment: Also, please take a look at: [Why not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @BenjaminW. yep, -v functionality. allready using it |grep -v "*.mp3" but it is not working

Comment: grep takes a regex, not glob. Use `grep -v '.*\.mp3'`. But that matching `.*` is useless, just match `.mp3` - `grep -v '\.mp3'`

Comment: If you show a list of files in the current directory and the output you'd like to have, we probably can suggest a robust solution.